# bcp change value "," (komma) to "." (dot)

Tags: sql-server, csv, cmd, sqlcmd

I found out: if I do a

```
select Artikelnummer,Listenpreis*1.19 as money from [SL_M03KNE].[dbo].[ARKALK]
```

i get: 5,59

If i do a

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select Artikelnummer,Listenpreis*1.19 as money from [SL_M03KNE].[dbo].[ARKALK]" queryout "D:\shop\xml\Artikelpreise_ohne.csv" -E -c -T -x
```

i found in the csv File the Value 5.59

the bcp do a conversion from the komma to dot. How can i do it that the original 5,59 was insert in the csv?

Answer (score 1):

By default, `bcp` ignores regional settings.  From SQL Server 2012, you can use `bcp -R` to [honor regional settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx).

If you are using an older version of SQL Server, consider formatting the output in your query.  For example, use `replace` to change dots to commas:

```
select replace(convert(varchar(50), Listenpreis*1.19), '.', ',')
```

Comment: i use Server 2012 and i have try the -R but if do not work. from your second answer i get an Syntax error:     EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select Artikelnummer,replace(convert(varchar(50), Listenpreis*1.19), '.', ',') from [SL_M03KNE].[dbo].[ARKALK]" queryout "D:\shop\xml\Artikelpreise_ohne.csv" -R -c -T -Usa -Psomepass -Ssome/db -t;'

Comment: Because you are using `xp_cmdshell`, the regional setting that matters is that of the account SQL Server is running under.  The syntax error is surprising.  Try to write `1.19` as `1,19` ? (not sure!)

Comment: Are you escaping the single quotes when you pass the query to `xp_cmdshell` ? Like `xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select replace(col1,''.'','','')"'`

Comment: I think yes: EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select Artikelnummer,Listenpreis*1.19 as money from [SL_M03KNE].[dbo].[ARKALK]" queryout "D:\shop\xml\Artikelpreise_ohne.csv" -E -c -T -Usa -Psomepass -Ssome\db -t;'